# Problem with an input tag in a function - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to render an input tag conditionally so that is why I'm using a function instead of just putting it all into a return statement. The issue I'm encountering is whenever I type a single word into an input tag it looses focus and I have to click it again to re-gain focus. My code is like this:

```
function App() {
    function InputTag() {
        if (someCondition) {
            return (
                <input onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)} value={State} />
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <input disabled value={State} />
            )
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <InputTag />
        </div>
    )
}
```

After some de-bugging I've found that this issue occurs when I'm using a function to return an input tag but in my case I have to use a function to return the input tag.

You can experience this issue at : https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-bassi-3gmyk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InputTag` is being redefined every time `App` renders. And `App` is re-rendering every time the `onChange` event is fired because its state is being updated.

One solution would be to move `InputTag` outside of `App`, passing the state and state setter as component props.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [State, setState] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <InputTag State={State} setState={setState} />
    </div>
  );
}

function InputTag({ State, setState }) {
  return <input onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)} value={State} />;
}
```

[image: Edit boring-sara-l3yvr]

---

However, It's not so clear why you say you *need* to use a function to do some conditional rendering.

If you are only making the input disabled based on `someCondition`, you can easily do that in `App`'s return statement.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");
  const [someCondition, setSomeCondition] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}
        value={state}
        disabled={!someCondition}
      />

      <button onClick={() => setSomeCondition(!someCondition)}>
        someCondition: {someCondition.toString()}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit holy-framework-w8n1m]